# Move config.json out of Angular 2 application and access this external config.json file in Angular 2 code

Tags: java, angular, rest

I am developing an application that includes-

1) Angular 2 for front end

2) REST API's for web services to get data from database

3) IBM Websphere application server as the web container that hosts both the applications.

Both UI and REST are two different applications deployed on the same server.

The UI application war file consists of a config.json configuration file, that includes dynamic properties required by the application like-

1)Base URL of the REST API server.

This base URL can change from time to time.

Currently, this **config.json** file is packaged inside the UI application war file in **“assets”** folder. I am accessing this file inside UI code using **relative path as “./assets/config.json”.**

I want to move this file out of the UI application war. Then, I need to access this external config.json file in my angular code. This external config.json file can reside on the same server on which the UI application is running.

What is the best approach to access this external config.json file inside the angular code?

Comment: what approach did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple Web API with a config method that would return the data in json format. I assume you are using httpClient.get() to retrieve the file so you could just use that call and just pass the url of your configuration webAPI

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.httpClient.get<AppConfig>(configFile)
        .subscribe(config => {
            this.setAppConfig(config);
            resolve();
         });
})
```